# How to remove black space using Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using Navigation controller.

In my first screen their is no need of `NavigationBar`. As this is the Home screen.So I am hiding it using this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
```

When I push to new screen I am showing the NavigationBar using this code:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.navigationController NO];
}
```

The problem is when I come back from other screens to my HomeScreen I am getting black screen in place of navigationBar.

Here is the problem in Image:

[image]

White color screen is my ViewController which has navigation bar and BLue one has'n Navigation bar. How can I remove the black part.

Comment: The image link is broken. Check again

Comment: I dont have enough repo to post that image...please upvote my question so that i can upload it

Answer (score 0):

Click on the navigation controller and go to attribute inspector and uncheck the show navigation bar option as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: still i am getting that black space

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do it. All you need to do is create a subclass of `UINavigationController` class. Set the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. Add the following method in the class.

```
    - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([viewController isKindOfClass: [SomeClass class]])
        [self setNavigationBarHidden: NO];
    else
        [self setNavigationBarHidden: YES];
}
```

OR

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: I dont want to hide back button... I want when I switch from navigation bar then I dont want to see that black space which is occured because the screen it is going to open doesn't have navigaiton bar.